# pgAdmin 4 3.0 not launching on latest version of Win10 (1803)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

pgAdmin 4 is not launching on my PC.
It used to work, presumably until Win10 updated to latest version (1803) some days ago.

When I start it, a splash screen appears and disappears in seconds.
If I look at task manager, the process starts and stops.

If I directly connect to http://127.0.0.1:51122/browser/, I get connection refused because no backend is listening.

Any other experienced the same problem?

The version of pgAdmin 4 is 3.0, released in early april, packed with PG 9.6.

Comment: what pgadmin4 logs says?
Check pgadmin4.log for any errors. Ref:https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#8

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on Monday

Comment: Unfortunately, pgadmin4.log (for future reference, it is located under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin`) just contains a line from an old failed query.

Comment: Update: by typing `cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\bin` then `pgAdmin4.exe` in a sheel, I've been able to start pgAdmin 4 backend... not sure why double-clicking the executable crashes after few seconds...

Comment: If I type `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\bin\pgAdmin4.exe"` without prior changing directory, a fatal error windows appears: ***An error occured initialising the application server: Failed to launch the application server, server thread exiting***. Then a configuration window with the opportunity to set the ***Browser command*** appears.

Comment: I finally created a bat with `CD` and `pgAdmin4.exe`, and a link to it. Ridicolous. Pleas give us pgAdmin III back!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to locate where PGadmin was installed and make a new shortcut with a target like ""C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe"

Comment: In my installation, pgAdmin is under C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\bin but starting it from there changes nothing

Comment: Yes the pgadmin4.log is more for sql errors once PGadmin has started. Teejay have you tried uninstalling and reinstall PGadmin?

Comment: @Teejay I just noticed the independed installer puts it C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe even though the original location was in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\bin

Comment: @blindguy Yes, I already noticed that. It seems that pgAdmin is still 32-bit, but the PostgreSQL 64-bit installer puts it in the same directory of PsotgreSQL server. Anyway, moving it (or installing independently) doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when I changed Python-related path configurations in Windows 10, especially when I installed both Python 2 and 3. After deleting every path (related to Python), pgAdmin 4 worked well. There might be some path configuration that does not conflict with pgAdmin 4, but I was not able to find it yet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to check PATH variable